# Moving Servers to IaaS without sysprep azure-virtual-machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint, azure-virtual-machine, sysprep

azure-virtual-machine

Hello,

I am moving a bunch of servers from my datacentre to azure. Servers are test & development sharepoint & SQL. depending on how successful the migration is we will consider moving additional servers.

for this i have setup a site-to-site VPN which works as expected and is accessible from

next i followed instructions on the website, sysprep'ed the sharepoint & SQL servers, uploaded & created VMs of the 2 servers.

once assigned the new IP addresses, the servers have been facing various problems & 2 days later i am yet to get the services started.

Question:

1) relative to SQL & Sharepoint services, is sysprep recommended ? if yes, what all does sysprep knock off & would have to be re-configured on the migrated VM ?

note: i don't have a need to create multiple servers of this VM. just one move the servers from my datacentre to azure.

2) what are the implications of uploading the VHD without doing a sysprep ? what would break ? ( i know i would have to reconfigure the D: drive )

TIA.

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to sysprep a disk before you bring it into Azure. You can upload an image and create a VM with it without. When you create the Vm you use the 'fromimage' parameter.

In Azure's terms this is a [specialized](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/vm-image-blog-post/) Vm.

You can find templates for deploying them [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-from-specialized-vhd)